# Issue with Query joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, inner-join

I am getting an error on the query below.  I am not exactly sure why.

The query below is dynamic sql, that is set into variables and printed out.

Error Msg:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 60
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 77
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 86
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Query:

```
    SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT  vwGetMySDDocsLatest.Document_ID,
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.ViewPrintFlag AS ViewPrint,
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.ViewOnly,
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.DownloadFlag AS Download,
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.DocBookFlag AS DocBook,
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.Name_ID, 
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.SheetNo, 
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.SheetNoTotal, 
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.Title, 
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.Rev, 
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.Rev_Date,
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.Rev_Purpose_Code, 
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.[Filename], 
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.Extension,
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.DocumentNo,
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.ClientDocument_No,
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.DEL_DOCSTRING,
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.RE_Init,
                vwGetMySDDocsLatest.Project_ID  

            , 1 AS NumberOfRows , 1 AS NumberOfPages 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DocumentNo) As RN 
        FROM    vwGetMySDDocsLatest INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tblSDDocuments_REV.Document_ID FROM tblSDDocuments_REV  WHERE 1 = 1  ) AS DR2 ON vwGetMySDDocsLatest.Document_ID = DR2.Document_ID 
        WHERE vwGetMySDDocsLatest.Name_ID = 4362 AND
        vwGetMySDDocsLatest.Project_ID = 349 AND
        vwGetMySDDocsLatest.DocumentNo Like '%lp-0887-p01%' 
        ) AS newTBL 
                WHERE newTBL.RN BETWEEN 1 AND 25 ) AS onePage 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT tblSDDocuments_Rev.DocumentRev_ID AS R_DocumentRev_ID , 
                        tblSDDocuments_Rev.Document_ID AS R_Document_ID, 
                        tblSDDocuments_Rev.Rev AS R_Rev, 
                        tblSDDocuments_Rev.Rev_Create_Date AS R_Rev_Create_Date, 
                        tblSDDocuments_Rev.Rev_Due_Date AS R_Rev_Due_Date, 
                        dbo.udfNameForward(tblSDDocuments_Rev.Rev_Due_From) AS  R_NameFrom, 
                        tblSDDocuments_Rev.Rev_Date AS R_Rev_Date, 
                        dbo.tblRev_Purpose.Rev_Purpose_Code AS R_Rev_Purpose_Code, 
                        tblSDDocuments_Rev.Flag AS R_Flag,
                        tblSDDocuments_Rev.Filename AS R_Filename, 
                        tblFileExtensions.Extension AS R_Extension,
                        tblSDDocuments_Rev.Client_Filename AS R_Client_Filename,
                        dbo.tblRev_Purpose.Allow_Matrix_View AS R_Allow_Matrix_View,
                        tblSDDocuments_Rev.Filename_Available AS R_Filename_Available,
                        tblSDDocuments_Rev.Filename_Available_Other AS R_Filename_Available_Other,
                        tblRev_Purpose.Rev_Purpose_ID AS R_Rev_Purpose_ID

                        FROM    tblSDDocuments_Rev 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblFileExtensions 
                        ON tblSDDocuments_Rev.Extension_id = tblFileExtensions.Extension_ID 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Name 
                        ON tblSDDocuments_Rev.Rev_Due_From = tbl_Name.Name_Id 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblRev_Purpose
                        ON tblSDDocuments_Rev.Rev_Purpose_ID = dbo.tblRev_Purpose.Rev_Purpose_ID  WHERE 1 = 1  ) AS TBLRevs

                    ON onePage.Document_ID = TBLRevs.R_Document_ID 
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT Document_ID AS MDID, MAX(DocumentREV_ID) AS MAXREV 
                                FROM tblSDDocuments_REV
                                --WHERE REV_Date IS NOT NULL
                                GROUP BY Document_ID) AS MAXTBL
                    ON MAXTBL.MDID = TBLRevs.R_Document_ID 

                     INNER JOIN ((SELECT Document_ID AS MDID2, MAX(REV_DATE) AS MAXREVDATE
                                FROM tblSDDocuments_REV
                                GROUP BY Document_ID) AS MAX1
                            INNER JOIN tblSDDocuments_REV R1 
                                ON MAX1.MAXREVDATE = R1.Rev_Date AND MAX1.MDID2 = R1.Document_ID)  AS MAXDATETBL
                    ON MAXDATETBL.MDID2 = TBLRevs.R_Document_ID


                    LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT td.document_Rev_ID, a.Approval_Abbr
                                    FROM tblsdtransmittal_documents td
                                        inner join tblsdtransmittal t
                                            on td.transmittal_id = t.transmittal_id
                                        inner join tblDocuments_ApprovalType a
                                            ON td.Approval_ID = a.Approval_ID
                                        inner join (
                                            SELECT MAX(t.created_date) AS LatestDate, td.Document_Rev_ID
                                            FROM tblsdtransmittal t
                                                INNER JOIN tblsdtransmittal_documents td
                                                    ON t.transmittal_id = td.transmittal_id
                                            WHERE t.to_supplier = 1
                                            GROUP by  td.Document_Rev_ID ) MAXDATE
                                        ON td.document_Rev_ID = maxdate.document_Rev_ID AND t.created_date = MAXDATE.LatestDate) AS APPRTBL
                    ON tblrevs.r_documentrev_id = APPRTBL.document_Rev_ID


                    LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT  SDRevComments_ID AS ETRevComments_ID, 
                            SDRevComments_RevID AS ETRevComments_RevID, 
                            SDRevComments_New_Filename AS ETRevComments_New_Filename, 
                            SDRevComments_Orig_Filename AS ETRevComments_Orig_Filename,
                            SDRevComments_Description AS ETRevComments_Description
                    FROM    tblSDDocuments_Rev_Comments) AS COMTBL
                    ON TBLRevs.R_DocumentREV_ID = COMTBL.ETRevComments_RevID
                     WHERE MAXTBL.MAXREV = TBLRevs.R_DocumentRev_ID   ---check for latest/all revs  

                    ORDER BY    DocumentNo ,TBLRevs.R_Document_ID, TBLRevs.R_DocumentRev_ID DESC
```

If I remove this part of the query:

```
             INNER JOIN ((SELECT Document_ID AS MDID2, MAX(REV_DATE) AS MAXREVDATE
                        FROM tblSDDocuments_REV
                        GROUP BY Document_ID) AS MAX1
                    INNER JOIN tblSDDocuments_REV R1 
                        ON MAX1.MAXREVDATE = R1.Rev_Date AND MAX1.MDID2 = R1.Document_ID)  AS MAXDATETBL
            ON MAXDATETBL.MDID2 = TBLRevs.R_Document_ID
```

It runs great.  Any idea on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an extra bracket ( just after INNER JOIN, loose it and try

```
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Document_ID AS MDID2, MAX(REV_DATE) AS MAXREVDATE
    FROM tblSDDocuments_REV
    GROUP BY Document_ID) AS MAX1
    INNER JOIN tblSDDocuments_REV R1 ON MAX1.MAXREVDATE = R1.Rev_Date AND MAX1.MDID2 = R1.Document_ID)  AS MAXDATETBL
ON MAXDATETBL.MDID2 = TBLRevs.R_Document_ID
```

Comment: The parenthesis are find for that part of the query.  There are 2 opening parenthesis before the select statement. The corresponding closing parenthesis are after the Group By ... ) and after the last part of the inner join. If I remove one as suggested above, the query has different problems.

Comment: after first parenthesis you have to select some columns, there is just inner join no column selection.

Answer (score 0):

The issue *is* with this fragment:

```
 INNER JOIN ((SELECT Document_ID AS MDID2, MAX(REV_DATE) AS MAXREVDATE
            FROM tblSDDocuments_REV
            GROUP BY Document_ID) AS MAX1
        INNER JOIN tblSDDocuments_REV R1 
            ON MAX1.MAXREVDATE = R1.Rev_Date AND MAX1.MDID2 = R1.Document_ID)  AS MAXDATETBL
ON MAXDATETBL.MDID2 = TBLRevs.R_Document_ID
```

The problem is assigning an alias (`MAXDATETBL`) to the result of a join. Apparently SQL Server doesn't like that, and indeed you don't need that alias. The columns in that internal inner join's resulting set are supposed to be referenced using aliases of the tables which contributed to the join. That is, instead of `MAXDATETBL.MDID2` you should specify `MAX1.MDID2`:

```
 INNER JOIN ((SELECT Document_ID AS MDID2, MAX(REV_DATE) AS MAXREVDATE
            FROM tblSDDocuments_REV
            GROUP BY Document_ID) AS MAX1
        INNER JOIN tblSDDocuments_REV R1 
            ON MAX1.MAXREVDATE = R1.Rev_Date AND MAX1.MDID2 = R1.Document_ID)  AS MAXDATETBL
ON MAX1.MDID2 = TBLRevs.R_Document_ID
```

You could even omit the brackets around the internal join. They are allowed but are superfluous, because the syntax makes it clear that the right side of the INNER JOIN at the beginning of the fragment is in fact a join between `MAX1` and `R1` rather than `MAX` alone.